# Form Type Extension with a different name that parent

Tags: symfony

I wrote a Form Type Extension using this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html
in order to extend the File widget.

However, I don't want all my file widgets to use this extension but only some of them. Is it possible to specify a different name/tag to my extension so that I can specify whether I want to use it or not?

For example, now I use it like this :

```
$builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('file', 'file', array('image_path' => 'webPath'));
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('file', 'imagefile', array('image_path' => 'webPath'));
```

The goal is to use the "imagefile" type for my image uploads and the basic file widget for the other kind of files.

Answer (score 0):

OK the principle was just to create a Custom Form field type instead of an extension. It's almost the same idea.

More information here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html